# Scroll DOM Element from a non-scrollable element

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've made a small Codepen clarify my problem: https://codepen.io/valentin-wei/pen/YzZNOKW
I want to scroll the inner paragraph when I scroll anywhere on the page even on the non-scrollable div.pageContent.

So what I need is something like

```
domElement.scrollTop += x
```

However, it seems that "x" is different depending on the used browser or mouse settings.
Note: I don't want to use jquery.

Is there any way to implement this behavior so the user has a "native" scrolling experience?

Comment: Did you try `mousewheel` link: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/wheel_event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression `when I scroll anywhere on the page` probably means when you send a trigger that can lead to a scroll, like a `wheel` event. If that is the case, you can just use the `dy` property of the `wheel` event:

```js
let el = document.querySelector('p');
window.addEventListener('wheel', function(e){
  let dy = e.deltaY;
  el.scrollTop += dy;
});
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.pageContent {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.pageContent > p {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="pageContent">
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.   

Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.   

Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi.   

Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet doming id quod mazim placerat facer
    </p>
</div>
```